# Tyres installed in original position

Tags: probability, combinations

> After summer, the winter tyres of a car (with four wheels) are to be put back. However, the owner has forgotten which tyre goes to which wheel, and the tyres are installed `randomly', each of the 4!=24 permutations being equally likely. What is the expected number of tyres that are installed in their original positions?

I got my answer using the linearity of expectation from [What is the expected number of tyres that are installed in their original positions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401536/what-is-the-expected-number-of-tyres-that-are-installed-in-their-original-positi) but wanted to try simpler approach $E[X] = \sum xp(x)$

I was trying to use the method of combinations but I'm getting stuck.

$P(4 \ tyre) = 1/24$ because there is only 1 order where all 4 tyres are in their original position. Why doesn't $ \frac{4C1}{24}$ work ? What am I missing from the equation?

$P(3 \ tyre) = 0$ because if 3 tyres are installed correctly then the 4th is as well.

$P(1 \ tyre) = \frac{(4)(2)}{24}$ because there are 4 tyres to select from then of the remaining 3, only 2 can be selected.

$P(2 \ tyre) = \frac{(4)(3)}{24}$ because there are 4 tyres to select from then 3 tyres. This is wrong.

Can someone explain how I can use combinations here?

Comment: Your question somehow proves that $\mathbb E[X]=\sum xp(x)$ is not a simpler approach (as you state) but a more complex approach. Especially the fact that this question can be solved without combinations makes me reluctant to think about these combinations. If you are asked to compute expectations then start by looking for a method that avoids the calculation of the (often complex) distribution.

Comment: If you read the solutions to the linked problem, you will see a number of ways of correctly counting the number of arrangements with exactly one tyre and exactly two tyres in their proper positions.

Answer (score 1):

We can count number of combinations $A(n)$ where $n$ tyres are on the right position:

- 1 tire - we select one tire out of $4$ ($\binom{4}{1}$ ways) and place it on it's place. Then we take a tire from the same axle and place it on the other axle ($\binom{2}{1}$ ways). Then we place the remaining wheels on the wrong places. 
  $$A(1) = \binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}=8$$
- 2 tires - we select two tires out of $4$ ($\binom{4}{2}$ ways) and place it on it's place. Then we place the remaining wheels on the wrong places. 
  $$A(2)= \binom{4}{2}=6$$
- 3 tires - if we place 3 tires on it's place, then the remaining tire would also be placed on it's place.
  $$A(3)=0$$
- 4 tires - take four tires out of 4 ($\binom{4}{4}$ ways) and place them on the right places.
  $$A(4)=\binom{4}{4}= 1$$

Then we can compute probabilities of this cases:
$$P(1)=\frac{1}{3}, P(2)=\frac{1}{4}, P(3)=0, P(4)=\frac{1}{24}$$
and the expected value:
$$E=\frac{1}{3}+2\cdot \frac{1}{4} + 3\cdot 0 + 4\cdot \frac{1}{24} = \frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{6}+0+\frac{1}{6}=1$$